# existing record validation

Tags: java, sql

I want to check if there's a existing applicant record in my application table. if not continue to new application to fill up the form.

here's my method:

```
public List<Tbcifindividual> existingApplication(String lastname, String firstname, Date dob) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DBService dbservice = new DBServiceImpl();
        Map<String,Object> params  = HQLUtil.getMap();
        List<Tbcifindividual> list = new ArrayList<Tbcifindividual>();
        try {
            params.put("lastname", lastname);
            params.put("firstname", firstname);
            params.put("dob", dob);
            System.out.println("lastname >>>>>>>: " +lastname);
            System.out.println("firstname>>>>>>>: " +firstname);
            System.out.println("dob>>>>>>>>>: " +dob);

            list = (List<Tbcifindividual>)dbservice.executeListHQLQuery("FROM Tbcifindividual WHERE firstname=:firstname"
                    + " and lastname=:lastname and CONVERT(DATE,dateofbirth,120)=CONVERT(DATE,:dob,120)", params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

the problem is in the query

```
FROM Tbcifindividual WHERE firstname=:firstname and lastname=:lastname and CONVERT(DATE,dateofbirth,120)=CONVERT(DATE,:dob,120)
```

it works when I inputted existing record.

```
sample(existing record in my table)
firstname: test
lastname: test
DOB: 1/1/1991
output: you have a pending application.
```

i will display the record on a `dojogrid`

---

But when i try to input a diff. `DOB`

```
sample: (doesn't exist in my table for pending applicant)
fistname: test
lastname: test
DOB: 1/1/1990
output: you have a pending application.
```

But no record displayed on the `dojogrid` since its suppose to be a new application since `DOB` is different from the existing record

this is the result of sysout:

```
lastname >>>>>>>: TEST
firstname>>>>>>>: TEST
dob>>>>>>>>>: Sun Jan 01 02:00:00 SGT 1990
```

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: Don't post your code as an image, past the code and use the correct tags, it will be much more readable and would be better for search engine references.

Comment: @DhavalAsodariya firstname = varchar(100) lastname = varchar(100) dateofbirth = datetime

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace and try equating the date directly, like dob = input date (sql converted date from user).